# Can you make a cross subdomain form POST (non-javascript)?

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I found lots of answers regarding AJAX calls, but I had trouble finding an answer for just a straight up HTML form without using Javascript.

Can you post a form from `foo.mydomain.com/somepage` to `bar.mydomain.com/someotherpage`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I found lots of answers regarding AJAX calls, but I had trouble finding an answer for just a straight up HTML form without using Javascript.

Sure. You can post forms wherever you want, including other domains, ports, and even protocols.

The only thing you *can't* do is submit a form pointing to a different domain, port or protocol into an iframe, and then try to access its contents using JavaScript. That gets blocked by the Same Origin Policy (this can be overcome for subdomains though I think). Other than that, forms have no restrictions.

Comment: It can be overcome for *any* domain if the server responds with a specific header allowing cross domain access - [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control)

Comment: Hmm... might need to do some redirecting though. If you submit to a separate domain, wouldn't that domain need to handle the request and deliver you to a confirmation page?

Comment: Well, let's say you serve your static content out of an S3 bucket or some other static store from example.com, but you submit forms to api.example.com, where maybe you have API Gateway, or some JSON REST API server. It might be a bit tricky to handle those users with JavaScript disabled. They'll land on api.example.com/something with their browser, and raw JSON output.

Comment: @Costa hmm. In that case you would either have to emit a server-side redirect in the response header (to the thank you page) when the user hits that endpoint, or have two sorts of events on the original form: one (the plain action URL) for non-JS users leading to a human readable page that makes the API call for you and says "thank you" when it succeeds, and one (by manipulating `onsubmit`) for Javascript users. Although I'm not sure how this even works for users with JS enabled? If you just submit a form to a JSON REST API, you would see the raw JSON with or without Javascript enabled, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's very creative. I hadn't thought of those aspects as separate. I might just ignore users with no JavaScript. Sadly, it's a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Costa yeah, depending on your target audience that's a real option. It's a shame and in an ideal world we would all support non-JS users, but building things takes time and is expensive

Answer (score 1):

Just use an include the hostname in the `action` attribute.

```
<form action="//bar.example.com/someotherpage" method="post">
```

Comment: Does the `//` mean use the same protocol e.g. http vs https?